# How to measure the pulse width in Plot Graph?

Tags: plotting, signal-processing

I'm practicing "Inverse Fourier transform" with impulse train 
using Diracdelta function.

Condition

1. Wavelength: 800(nm)
2. Velocity of Lingt: 299,792,458(m/s)
3. Using 1 and 2 >> Frequency0 = 299,792,458(m/s) / 800(nm)
4. Interval of each frequency: 20Thz
5. Number of Frequency mode: N=20

Please refer to code below.

My question is

"How can I measure the time band-width in Plot graph?"

(Detail is in the image below and there are two questions."

Anybody who can solve this question, Please help me. Thank you.!

---

```
\[Lambda] = 800 10^-9 ;                   (*Wavelength(m)*)
V = 299792458;                (*Velocity of Lingt(m/s)*)
freq0 = V/\[Lambda];                        (*Frequency(Hz))*)
\[Delta] = 
 20 10^12;                         (*Interval of Each Frequency(Hz)*)
\


A = Sum[DiracDelta[\[Omega] - (freq0 + i \[Delta])], {i, 0, 
   19}]; (*Get 20 Frequency Mod Using Diracdelta Function*)
B = InverseFourierTransform[A, \[Omega], t, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, 1}] ;
Plot[A, {\[Omega], 0, 2 freq0}]
Plot[Re[B], {t, -150 (freq0)^-1, 150 (freq0)^-1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1000]
Plot[(Abs[B])^2, {t, -150 (freq0)^-1, 150 (freq0)^-1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: The function `FindPeaks[]` may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @LouisB, `FindPeaks` function can be used as follows.

Firstly, generate data for `Re[B]` and `Abs[B]`. In this case, the number of points are `2001`.

```
\[Lambda] = 800 10^-9; V = 299792458;
freq0 = V/\[Lambda]; 
\[Delta] = 20 10^12; 
A = Sum[DiracDelta[\[Omega] - (freq0 + i \[Delta])], {i, 0, 19}]; 
B[t_] = InverseFourierTransform[A, \[Omega], t, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];
step = (2*150. (freq0)^-1)/2000;
xP = Range[-150. (freq0)^-1, 150. (freq0)^-1, step];
yReB = Re /@ B /@ xP;
yAbsB = Abs[#]^2 & /@ B /@ xP;
```

Secondly, find the peaks which are greater than some value. In this case, you can choose a value of 3.

```
peaksReB = FindPeaks[yReB, Automatic, Automatic, 3];
(*{{209, 3.01067}, {1001, 3.1831}, {1793, 3.01067}}*)
peaksAbsB = FindPeaks[yAbsB, Automatic, Automatic, 3];
(*{{216, 10.1317}, {1001, 10.1321}, {1786, 10.1317}}*)
```

Then, find the slopes for the left and right lines of the peaks.

```
slopesReB = 
  Extract[Differences[yReB], {{# - 4}, {# + 4}}] & /@ 
   peaksReB[[;; , 1]];
slopesAbsB = 
  Extract[Differences[yAbsB], {{# - 8}, {# + 8}}] & /@ 
   peaksAbsB[[;; , 1]];
```

Finally, find the halfpeak values.

```
halfPeaksReBX = (-(peaksReB[[;; , 2]]/(2 slopesReB)) + 
    peaksReB[[;; , 1]]);
halfPeaksAbsBX = (-(peaksAbsB[[;; , 2]]/(2 slopesAbsB)) + 
    peaksAbsB[[;; , 1]]);
halfPeaksReB = 
  Flatten[#, 1] &@
   MapThread[
    Tuples@{#1, {#2}} &, {halfPeaksReBX, peaksReB[[;; , 2]]/2}];
(*{{205.882, 1.50534}, {211.465, 1.50534}, {997.941, 1.59155}, {1003.6, 
1.59155}, {1790.02, 1.50534}, {1795.72, 1.50534}}*)
halfPeaksAbsB = 
  Flatten[#, 1] &@
   MapThread[
    Tuples@{#1, {#2}} &, {halfPeaksAbsBX, peaksAbsB[[;; , 2]]/2}];
(*{{199.026, 5.06583}, {231.843, 5.06583}, {983.762, 5.06606}, {1016.64,
 5.06606}, {1768.49, 5.06583}, {1801.44, 5.06583}}*)
```

To get the time bandwidth between the peaks for `Re[B]`:

```
Differences@peaksReB[[;; , 1]]*step
(*{3.17019*10^-13, 3.17019*10^-13}*)
```

To get the time bandwidth at 50% peak for `Re[B]`:

```
-Subtract @@@ Partition[halfPeaksReB[[;; , 1]]*step, 2]
(*{2.23447*10^-15, 2.26314*10^-15, 2.28138*10^-15}*)
```

Similarly, you can find the same parameters for `Abs[B]^2`.

`Re[B]`:

```
ListLinePlot[yReB, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], 
   Point[Join @@ {peaksReB, halfPeaksReB}]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

`Abs[B]`:

```
ListLinePlot[yAbsB, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], 
   Point[Join @@ {peaksAbsB, halfPeaksAbsB}]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]